# Joins not returning correct results. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, join

When I run my query it only gives one record by counting all the records in one row, it should output the records against each `a.tech_id` . Why my joins not working ?

```
select 
    concat(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as name, 
    u.skill, 
    ut.name as team_name,
    (count(if(a.tech_id = u.user_id AND a.qc_id = 0 AND a.status = 2,1,0))) AS assigned_scopes,
    (count(if(a.tech_id = u.user_id  AND a.qc_id > 0 AND a.status = 3,1,0))) AS assigned_qa,
    (count(if(a.assignment_id=o.assignment_id and a.tech_id = u.user_id  AND a.status = 2 AND a.qc_id = 0 and o.class_id= 3,1,0))) AS assigned_canvass,
from am_ts_order o 
left join am_ts_assignment a
    ON a.assignment_id=o.assignment_id
left join am_user u
    ON a.tech_id=u.user_id
left join user_team ut
    ON u.user_team_id = ut.user_team_id
where u.user_role_id = 15
    and u.user_team_id = ut.user_team_id
order by u.first_name asc
```

Comment: You need a group by since you're using the count() function to determine which rows it collects the info on.

Comment: group by a.tech_id solved my problem here

Comment: You commented to me on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248128/correct-way-of-using-left-outer-join-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment77486744_45248128) but now it is deleted.

Comment: Sorry Sir I had to delete the question  because of negative score :(

Comment: Actually I made a sqlfiddle to show you my problem
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25c6dd0/1

Comment: Should I repost my question?

Comment: I have made a sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25c6dd0/4 . users with id 100 and 118 have 0 records for assigned_scopes, assigned_qa, failed_qa and assigned_canvass . So it does not display it just showed the record for user with id 210 . What I really need is to display all the users with 0 in each column if they have nothing. How Can I do this?

Comment: [Just post the new question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174154/266284) But make it a *better* and a *good* question, per the many links on the help page(s) including [mcve]. I don't have access to all that page (just a google cache of it), but do everything I said. Give us enough clear description of what your query is supposed to return for arbitrary valid input that we could program it only knowing what is in your question.  Use text, not links. Give input, DDL, desired output. You can give a bad query & error(s) & output. But mostly explain what a correct query returns.

Comment: PS I can't make sense of your last comment. Because you haven't explained desired output in terms of arbitrary valid input.  And because you havn't shown correct output for some small input--but not too small to show important cases. Best is, for each table--base or query result--tell us what a row in it says in terms of its column names. Do all that. Be *clear*. We can't read your mind. And an example given when you haven't explained what it is an example *of* is no example. Also is it *minimal*? Can you cause the problem with less? (So--that is not yet a good/mvce fiddle.) PS "15"????

Comment: PPS In an earlier comment I said ask a new question, but I forgot that maybe I answered it (I have a draft, anyway) & there were other clear comments you have not reacted to in [the repost by harron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261775/how-to-use-left-outer-join-in-mysql-to-get-my-desirable-results#). That's *all been repeated* at the repost, which is only better in that it gives an sqlfiddle & desired output. *Please* act on my comments here. And read a definition of left join. Also, *test your queries incrementally as you add joins & columns*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using functions like count, sum, etc., you need to add a group by clause to control the grouping of the results:

```
select 
    concat(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as name, 
    u.skill, 
    ut.name as team_name,
    (count(if(a.tech_id = u.user_id AND a.qc_id = 0 AND a.status = 2,1,0))) AS assigned_scopes,
    (count(if(a.tech_id = u.user_id  AND a.qc_id > 0 AND a.status = 3,1,0))) AS assigned_qa,
    (count(if(a.assignment_id=o.assignment_id and a.tech_id = u.user_id  AND a.status = 2 AND a.qc_id = 0 and o.class_id= 3,1,0))) AS assigned_canvass,
from am_ts_order o 
left join am_ts_assignment a
    ON a.assignment_id=o.assignment_id
left join am_user u
    ON a.tech_id=u.user_id
left join user_team ut
    ON u.user_team_id = ut.user_team_id
where u.user_role_id = 15
    and u.user_team_id = ut.user_team_id
order by u.first_name asc
group by a.tech_id
```

**UPDATE:**

This query alters the IF conditions to test if a matching row was found in some of the left joined tables:

```
select 
    concat(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as name, 
    u.skill, 
    ut.name as team_name,
    count(if(
        (NOT a.tech_id IS NULL) AND 
        (NOT u.user_id IS NULL) AND 
        a.qc_id = 0 AND 
        a.status = 2,1,0)) AS assigned_scopes,
    count(if(
        (NOT a.tech_id IS NULL) AND 
        a.qc_id > 0 AND 
        a.status = 3,1,0)) AS assigned_qa,
    count(if(
        (NOT a.assignment_id IS NULL) AND
        a.assignment_id = o.assignment_id AND 
        a.tech_id = u.user_id AND 
        a.status = 2 AND 
        a.qc_id = 0 AND 
        o.class_id= 3,1,0)) AS assigned_canvass,
from am_ts_order o 
left join am_ts_assignment a
    ON a.assignment_id=o.assignment_id
left join am_user u
    ON a.tech_id=u.user_id
left join user_team ut
    ON u.user_team_id = ut.user_team_id
where u.user_role_id = 15
    and u.user_team_id = ut.user_team_id
order by u.first_name asc
group by a.tech_id
```

Comment: this works but I need one more help, the count() for different columns is giving the same values for all columns, can you please check what is wrong with it?

Comment: In the IF() inside your count(), you repeat some of the JOIN conditions. Why?

Comment: I need the results from same table on different conditions

Comment: That's not the part I'm referring to. Specifically, ```a.tech_id = u.user_id```. Unless you're testing if the left join found a matching row, it's not needed in the IF. Edit your question and show your table schemas.

Comment: Do the JOINs need to be left joins? IOW, will some of the joined tables not have matching rows while others will?

Comment: yes this part a.tech_id = u.user_id is unnecessary in IF() I have checked by removing that.

Comment: No the matching rows will be in both tables. Let me edit the question and show you the schema

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149842/discussion-between-mehar44-and-sloan-thrasher).